# ruby on rails style configuration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

My ruby on rails app needed bootstrap and js, so I tried to add them.
Even though both styles are in the same folder, some of them are loading and some are not.

im getting

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/lib/uniform.default.css")
```

and other css modules

i tried to add everything into my manifest.js but no luck

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js


//= link_tree ../img
//= link_tree ../css 
//= link_tree ../js
//= link_tree ../font

//= link bookmarklet.coffee
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `lib` folder in your `app/assets/stylesheets`, e.g.:

```bash
mkdir app/assets/stylesheets/lib
```

Then put your `uniform.default.css` file into this folder

Comment: Thank you for the replay Dorian but still its not working

Comment: maybe try to put the file in `public/lib/`